# Error when using Browsershot with Laravel on Forge-provisioned server

Tags: node.js, laravel, puppeteer, laravel-forge

I'm using [Browsershot](https://github.com/spatie/browsershot) (which uses [Puppeteer](https://github.com/GoogleChrome/puppeteer)) with Laravel. I have it running perfectly in my local dev environment (Mac, Laravel Valet), but when running it on a Forge provisioned server, I get the following error in my log file (I've replaced sensitive URLs with placeholders):

```
local.ERROR: The command "PATH=$PATH:/usr/local/bin NODE_PATH=`/usr/bin/node /usr/bin/npm root -g` /usr/bin/node '/home/forge/my-app.co.uk/vendor/spatie/browsershot/src/../bin/browser.js' '{"url":"https:\/\/my-test-site.com\/about.html","action":"screenshot","options":{"type":"png","path":"\/home\/forge\/my-app.com\/storage\/screenshots\/13\/full\/21.jpg","args":[],"viewport":{"width":1400,"height":1080},"fullPage":true,"waitUntil":"networkidle0"}}'" failed.

Exit Code: 1(General error)
```

I've followed the instructions from the readme for installing the latest version of stable Chrome:

```
curl -sL https://deb.nodesource.com/setup_8.x | sudo -E bash -
sudo apt-get install -y nodejs gconf-service libasound2 libatk1.0-0 libc6 libcairo2 libcups2 libdbus-1-3 libexpat1 libfontconfig1 libgcc1 libgconf-2-4 libgdk-pixbuf2.0-0 libglib2.0-0 libgtk-3-0 libnspr4 libpango-1.0-0 libpangocairo-1.0-0 libstdc++6 libx11-6 libx11-xcb1 libxcb1 libxcomposite1 libxcursor1 libxdamage1 libxext6 libxfixes3 libxi6 libxrandr2 libxrender1 libxss1 libxtst6 ca-certificates fonts-liberation libappindicator1 libnss3 lsb-release xdg-utils wget
sudo npm install --global --unsafe-perm puppeteer
sudo chmod -R o+rx /usr/lib/node_modules/puppeteer/.local-chromium
```

My code looks like this:

I've also tried specifying custom node and npm binaries. I've also tried a custom include path. When doing so, the error I get may vary slightly, but remains essentially the same.

I'm actually installing Puppeteer as part of my build process in Forge. I set that up before I noticed the instructions for installing Chrome in the Browsershot readme.

I'm just not sure how to interpret that Node error. I've tried everything I can think of. So I'm hoping someone can point me in the right direction.

Thanks!

Comment: I know this is ancient, but did you resolve this? I'm in the exact same situation.

Comment: I also wonder this. Thank you

Comment: Edit. Actually, I got it to work with the curl sudo snippet from Spatie's docs.